# Removing extensions from needing to be entered on a website

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Ive read tons of threads and questions here already on this, i cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Im trying to make it so when i go to my website i dont have to enter .html to get to the page
ex: www.yoursite.com/help instead of www.yoursite.com/help.html

ive tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* $0.html
```

in my .htaccess file and it does not work.

You still get redirected to my error page whenever attempting without .html in the url

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Update: .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error.php
ErrorDocument 408 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with the entire contents of your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php 
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php 
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php 
ErrorDocument 405 /error.php 
ErrorDocument 408 /error.php 
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php 
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php 
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Source:
http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: This didnt work. I tried everything on that webpage. D:

Comment: Is your apache configured to utilize .htaccess?

Comment: remove anything else in the .htacess first, then follow the instructions in that link.

Comment: @udonsoup16 - That won't make a difference. If it was set to `None`, the OP's `.htaccess` file wouldn't be loaded at all.

Comment: @MikeAnthony I thought the same, but he says he has a redirect error page working via .htacess

Comment: @udonsoup16 - That's what I'm saying. Those wouldn't even work if `AllowOverride` was off. Also, most shared environments have it set appropriately, with no way to change it.

Comment: OP, post the contents of the .htaccess file.